# Cannot open Local files using href

Tags: file-permissions, html5

no matter where I placed the file...
on Chrome download folder
on Edge download folder

I run OS Android 13 / Galaxy S21

sample:
href="file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/MEGA Downloads/A_current_Trip/aaa.pdf"
I get: about:blank#blocked

I read many suggestions.
None worked for me.

It works perfect on Android 8.1

any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's the expected behavuor, due to [scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/#scoped-storage)